# R - Data frame to matrix for 2-dimensional values?

Tags: r

I have a matrix such as:

```
> mt <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3, ncol=3)
> dimnames(mt) <- list( c('a','b','c'), c('x','y','z') )
> mt
  x y z
a 1 4 7
b 2 5 8
c 3 6 9
```

I can convert it into a tabular format with:

```
> as.data.frame(as.table(mt))
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    a    x    1
2    b    x    2
3    c    x    3
4    a    y    4
5    b    y    5
6    c    y    6
7    a    z    7
8    b    z    8
9    c    z    9
```

My question is - Is there a clean way to do the reverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use: `?xtabs` :Create a contingency table (optionally a sparse matrix) from cross-classifying factors, usually contained in a data frame, using a formula interface.

```
 xtabs(Freq~Var1+Var2,Data)
    Var2
Var1 x y z
   a 1 4 7
   b 2 5 8
   c 3 6 9
```

You can also use this :  `?acsat`:Use acast or dcast depending on whether you want vector/matrix/array output or data frame output. Data frames can have at most two dimensions.

```
library(reshape2)
zz <- "Var1 Var2 Freq
1    a    x    1
2    b    x    2
3    c    x    3
4    a    y    4
5    b    y    5
6    c    y    6
7    a    z    7
8    b    z    8
9    c    z    9"
Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)

acast(Data, Var1 ~ Var2)
Using Freq as value column: use value.var to override.
  x y z
a 1 4 7
b 2 5 8
c 3 6 9
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `reshape2::acast`:

```
require(reshape2)
acast(m,Var1~Var2)

#  x y z
#a 1 4 7
#b 2 5 8
#c 3 6 9
```

ps: you can use `reshape2::melt()` to go the other way